# Rails 3 Capistrano Deployment Error (parsing a block node at ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, yaml

I'm trying to deploy a rails 3.2.11 app onto bluehost shared hosting using capistrano. I keep getting this error

```
 [myapp.com] executing command
*** [err :: myapp.com] rake aborted!
*** [err :: myapp.com] (<unknown>): did not find expected node content while parsing a block node at line 18 column 13
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/releases/20130115050636/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
*** [err :: myapp.com] /home2/myappc/rails_apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The error says `(<unknown>): did not find expected node content while parsing a block node at line 18 column 13`, but I have no idea which file it's actually referring to.

This is the `database_configuration` on line 4 in the log file above

```
# Loads and returns the contents of the #database_configuration_file. The
      # contents of the file are processed via ERB before being sent through    
      # YAML::load.                                                             
      def database_configuration
        require 'erb'
        YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(paths["config/database"].first)).result)
      end
```

I looked around and it might be YAML parsing error. 
So I tried to use this in irb to see if any `.yml` file is causing the trouble

```
YAML.load_file("filename.yml")
```

But they all turn out fine.

This is my Gemfile if it's needed

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'devise'
gem 'friendly_id', "~> 4.0.9"#, :git => "git://github.com/norman/friendly_id.git"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'json'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rqrcode-rails3' #imageqrcodes
gem 'mini_magick'
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  # gem 'thin' # Server used in production
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'execjs', '1.4.0'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Could be an issue with the version of `rake`. Can you run any rake command without an error? Try running `rake db:migrate:status`

Comment: what happens when you run `YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(paths["config/database"].first)).result)` in irb?

Comment: @AmirF it says `NameError: uninitialized constant ERB`

Comment: I think I have found the problem, `block node at line 18 column 13` is referring to my password for the database. Since I have bunch of symbols in the password, YAML couldn't parse it. I tried to put double quotes around them, still won't work. Does any one know the correct way to parse symbol in yml file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in my `database.yml` file. My password started with a symbol. I couldn't find a way to escape it, so I changed it and it works like a charm now.